# chemformula and common organic chemistry groups

Tags: code, chemistry, chemformula

What would be the proper (and efficient) way to type common organic groups/radicals/substituents like *i*-Pr, *n*-Bu or *t*-Bu with `chemformula` (the main concern is the prefixes)?

So far I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

Tetra-\textit{n}-butylammonium cation:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \ch{\textit{n-}Bu4N+}
    \item \ch{ $n\text{-}$ Bu4N+}
    \item \ch{ "\textit{n-}" Bu4N+}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Third version looks the best, but I find my code too cumbersome. I only found `\tert` command in `chemmacros` manual which produces *tert*, and is intended for the names, not formulas. Something tells me there must be more elegant (and semantically correct) way of typing this.

Comment: Maybe the `bpchem` package would help.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your suggestion, I flipped through the manual, but unfortunately I didn't find anything related.

Comment: Is `\item $n$-\ch{Bu4N+}` acceptable?

Comment: @SandyG `$n$-\ch{Bu4N+}` makes me feel uncomfortable since it breaks code semantics: *n-* is the part of the chemical formula, not a math symbol.

Comment: You could define your own command like `\newcommand{\nn}{\textit{n-}}` and use it like `\ch{\nn Bu4N+}`.

Comment: @leandriis That's indeed a good solution, thank you. But ideally I thought `chemformula` would allow for even a simpler approach without manually defining these prefixes.

Comment: I would make the distinction between writing an abbreviated form of name (n-Bu4N) versus writing the chemical formula, which would be `\ch{CH3CH2CH2CH2)4N+}`. `\ch{}` is intended for the latter use, I believe, not the former. That's why you don't see the functionality you are seeking. Maybe Clemens will drop in here and tell us.

Comment: @Ross I think you got this backwards. IUPAC allows to use common abbreviations for organic groups in formulas and structures, but not in text. For example: "*i*-Pr" in formula, but "isopropyl" in text. Besides, writing `CH3CH2CH2CH2` instead of defined and accepted abbreviation *n*-Bu is a waste of space and makes it hard to quickly comprehend the formula (not to mention the information about what isomer it is would be lost).

Comment: Ok. So use `\ch{}` to format the subscript and superscript in Bu4N+ and wrap that with `\iupac{}` which will optimize the spacing around the -, thus: `\iupac{Tetra-\textit{n}-\ch{Bu4N+}}`. If you need to show hypenation points, add `|` or `\-`.

Comment: @Ross Subjectively, this is an overkill, and also not quite semantic. `\iupac{...}` is used for *names*, but again, I need a *formula*. Also note that *n*-Bu is practically never used alone, there is a bunch of other stuff on both side with quite complex formatting on its own (other elements, groups, symbols, abbreviations, charges etc.). Escaping with `\iupac{...}` and nested `\textit{...}` + `\ch{...}` makes it way too complicated. Referring to *The Fifth Element* movie, I'd prefer *Leeloo* over *Leeloominaï Lekatariba Lamina-Tchaï Ekbat De Sebat*:)

Comment: Like @leandriis I would define a command.

Comment: @clemens Thank you for appearing in this thread! So, there is no built-in functionality in `chemformula` for this (yet?:) )?

Comment: @andselisk that's right. IIRC the `chemstyle` package has ready made macros for some of those groups...

Comment: @clemens I totally forgot about `chemstyle` package! It indeed includes commands `\nPr`, `\iPr`, `\nBu`, `\iBu`, `\sBu`, `\tBu`.  Thank you for reminding about this gem:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To easily access descriptors (prefixes in chemical nomenclature) that are not already built in `chemmacros`' nomenclature module, you can define your own commands as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}
\newcommand{\nn}{\textit{n-}}
\begin{document}

Tetra-\textit{n}-butylammonium cation: \ch{ "\textit{n-}" Bu4N+}

\iupac{Tetra-\nn butylammonium cation}:  \ch{\nn Bu4N+}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As mentioned by clemens in the comments, there is also the `chemstyle` package, that provides the commands `\nPr`, `\iPr`, `\nBu`, `\iBu`, `\sBu`, `\tBu`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what's the meaning of the second "n" in `\nn` is?

Comment: The name of the command does not have any special meaning. In order to avoid problems with already defined one letter commands, I simply added a second `n`. But you can of course name the command however you like.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sometimes I'm overthinking too much. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since one need to define these commands anyway, I figured it might also be useful to define them as abbreviations and use `glossaries` package. According to [ACS Style Guide](http://pubs.acs.org/series/styleguide), common groups in organic chemistry don't necessarily have to be defined in text, but one might consider adding own abbreviated groups later. Then building own glossary list can be quite beneficial:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{nPr}{\textit{n}-Pr}{\textit{n}-propyl}
\newacronym{iPr}{\textit{i}-Pr}{isopropyl}
\newacronym{nBu}{\textit{n}-Bu}{\textit{n}-butyl}
\newacronym{iBu}{\textit{i}-Bu}{isobutyl}
\newacronym{sBu}{\textit{s}-Bu}{\textit{sec}-butyl}
\newacronym{tBu}{\textit{t}-Bu}{\textit{tert}-butyl}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsunsetall

Common groups in organic chemistry are: \gls{nPr}, \gls{iPr}, \gls{nBu}, \gls{iBu}, \gls{sBu}, \gls{tBu}.

Tetra-\textit{n}-butylammonium cation: \ch{\gls{nBu}4N+}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]